# Using jQuery to pass data to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a faux shopping cart page.  I have checkboxes with data properties on them and then a UL that should match each of the checkbox elements.  I would like to pass a data property from the checkbox to the corresponding UL items.  Do I add data properties to each of my list items and do a comparison match? How would I do this?  My HTML structure is below.

```
<!--Attendee checkbox list-->
<div id="attendeeList">
    <input type="checkbox" name="attendee" title="Attendee One" data-productname="Product Awesome" data-attendeename="AttendeeOne" data-optionprice="7.00" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attendee" title="Attendee Two" data-productname="Product Awesome"  data-attendeename="AttendeeTwo" data-optionprice="7.00" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attendee" title="Attendee Three" data-productname="Product Awesome"  data-attendeename="AttendeeThree" data-optionprice="7.00" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attendee" title="Attendee Four" data-productname="Product Awesome"  data-attendeename="AttendeeFour" data-optionprice="7.00" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attendee" title="Attendee Five" data-productname="Product Awesome"  data-attendeename="AttendeeFive" data-optionprice="7.00" />
</div>
 <!--On Page Shopping Cart-->
 <ul id="shoppingCart">
     <li id="AttendeeOne">
     <h5>Attendee One</h5>
       <ul class="attendeeProductList">
         <!--Need to append product name and price to this list-->
         <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="AttendeeTwo">
     <h5>Attendee Two</h5>
       <ul class="attendeeProductList">
         <!--Need to append product name and price to this list-->
         <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="AttendeeThree">
      <h5>Attendee Three</h5>
       <ul class="attendeeProductList">
         <!--Need to append product name and price to this list-->
         <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="AttendeeFour">
     <h5>Attendee Four</h5>
        <ul class="attendeeProductList">
         <!--Need to append product name and price to this list-->
         <li></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
   <li id="AttendeeFive">
     <h5>Attendee Five</h5>
      <ul class="attendeeProductList">
         <!--Need to append product name and price to this list-->
         <li></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Comment**

First off I don't know why I got down voted. It is a good question for those who are not well versed on how to traverse multiple objects in jQuery.  This is what I thought this site was for, was to ask questions and provide answers to those who need it, not to down vote a legitimate question. I provided the HTML structure, I needed the pointer to get me going in the right direction. Thank you for those who provided me the direction and an pointer to my outcome.

Comment: Can we start with what you have tried?

Comment: That is why I am asking.  I would like a direction to go.  How would I go about matching my LI id with the data-attendeename in jQuery.  Once I have that, I can do the rest of the appending the elements to the attendeeProductList.  My initial hurdle is the element matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have most of what is needed defined in markup although it's not exactly clear why you would need a list for each checkbox.

Here's something that would get you started

```
/* checkbox change handler */
$('#attendeeList :checkbox').change(function(){
    var data=$(this).data(),
        /* get jQuery selector for list from data */
        jQId = "#" + data.attendeename,
        $list=$(jQId).find('.attendeeProductList');

    if(this.checked){
        /* add element if checked*/
        var li= '<li>Name:'+ data.attendeename +', Price:'+data.optionprice+'</li>';
        $list.append(li);
    }else{
        /* empty list if unchecked*/
        $list.empty();
    }

})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pjnL8ab/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: I am populating the sublist with the products that correspond with the attendee.  I will try this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way I can think of would be to add an additional attribute to each of your checkboxes and ul elements, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="attendee" title="Attendee One" data-productname="Product Awesome" data-attendeename="AttendeeOne" data-optionprice="7.00" data-target="attendee-1"/>
<ul class="attendeeProductList" data-target="attendee-1">
```

You can then easily append your selected item to the matching `<ul>` element like this:

```
$('#attendeeList input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    var productName = $(this).attr('data-productname');
    var productPrice = $(this).attr('data-optionprice');
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');

    $('ul[data-target="' + target + '"]').append('<li>' + productName + ': ' + productPrice + '</li>');
});
```

Obviously `.on('click')` isn't the best method, you'd want to only append if the item was checked, and make sure to remove it if it was unselected. If you're going to be doing this on any scale, it's much better to use a library like knockout or backbone that can handle binding like this for you. Solutions to this sort of problem using exclusively jQuery can (and do) quickly turn into spaghetti code

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b03zscy2/)